# jQuery .each() method not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, each

I have an each method I'm leveraging to launch a tooltip relevant to the `<td>` it exists within.  Everything works great in IE, Chrome, Safari, but Firefox is completely missing the each method, and launching only the last tooltip in the DOM.

What gives?

http://jsfiddle.net/yus5b/

HTML:

```
<div class="stage">
    <div class="dealFinder">
      <h2 class="title">Deal Finder in Your Area</h2>
      <table cellpadding="5">
          <tr>
          <td class="text">
              <p class="makeModel"><a href="#">2012 Land Rover Range Rover Evoque</a><br>in Oak Lawn</p>
            <a class="youSave" href="#" onclick="return false"> You Save at Least $14,810</a>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <div class="inner">
                <b>2012 Land Rover Range Rover Evoque</b>
                <span>Your Price $19,330</span>
                <p>The National Average is <b>$21,500</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
            <td class="pic">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/113x75" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text">
            <p class="makeModel"><a href="#">2012 Land Rover Range Rover Evoque</a><br>in Oak Lawn</p>
            <a class="youSave" href="#" onclick="return false"> You Save at Least $14,810</a>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <div class="inner">
                <b>2012 Land Rover Range Rover Evoque</b>
                <span><small>Your Price</small> $19,330</span>
                <p>The National Average is <b>$21,500</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="pic">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/113x75" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div><!-- .dealFinder -->
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Tooltip
    $('.tooltip').hide();
    $('.text').each(function(e) {
      var self = this;
      var tooltip = $(self).find('.tooltip');
      var youSave = $(self).find('.youSave');
      $(youSave).mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(self).find(tooltip).fadeIn("slow");
      });
      $(youSave).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(self).find(tooltip).fadeOut("fast");
      });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Really?  2 downvotes? Explanations as to why would be great.  Its a clear question with a JSFiddle provided?

Comment: I see it launching the tool tip - its just that mouseleave is triggered since the tooltip gets focus and then causes it to disappear.  Using FF on Mac.

Comment: *"Its a clear question with a JSFiddle provided?"* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code If JSFiddle goes down or is bogged down (as it was yesterday and other times in the past) you question wouldn't be answerable.

Comment: @KevinB  I was unaware of that specification, thank you for enlightening me. Question has been updated with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for start it is written strange. Try :

```
$('.text .youSave').mouseenter(function(){
   var item = $(this);
   var tooltip = $('.tooltip', item.parent()).fadeIn();
});

//the same way for mouseleave
```

and give tooltips display : none by default why change it with js ?

I see the problem. Tooltip fadein where your mouse is and that fire event mouseleave. Easy to fix. Tooltip has to be .youSave element child:

```
   <a class="youSave" href="#" onclick="return false"><span> You Save at Least $14,810<span>
<div class="tooltip">
                  <div class="inner">
                    <b>2012 Land Rover Range Rover Evoque</b>
                    <span>Your Price $19,330</span>
                    <p>The Web2Carz National Average is <b>$21,500</b></p>
                  </div>
</a>
```

and then JS:

```
$('.text .youSave').mouseenter(function(){
   var item = $(this);
   var tooltip = $('.tooltip', item).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Good eye catching the necessary HTML structure changes.  This works for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There really should almost never be a need for an each function to iterate over elements just to bind them to event handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
    $('.youSave', '.text').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).next('.tooltip').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yus5b/4/)

The rest is just placement issues from placing the tooltip on top of the button, and should be fixable with a little CSS.

Comment: That is a much leaner snippet of jQuery, but the behavior is still the same in FFox.

Comment: It gets the right tooltip, but they are pretty much the same, I changed the text here : http://jsfiddle.net/yus5b/5/ to show that it does in fact get the right one. The other issue is just poor CSS placement.

Comment: I think I understand.  Firefox is having a touch time interpreting the `position: relative` of the parent `<td>` it seems.  Changing the tooltip to `position:relative` rather than `absolute` gave me tooltips in each `<td>`, granted it broke design, but showed in fact that separate tooltips were loading per relative parent element.